# Stuck with SQL repeating first row only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

OK, so here goes.

I'm trying to write a blogging system (learning how to anyway), and the problem I have is that SQL is only returning the first line in the database. It does it as many times as records I have. I can't work out what is going wrong. Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

```php
<?php 
    include "db_connect.php";
    include "functions.php";
    include "style/header.php";
?>

<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="main">

<?php
       echo 'Welcome to the forest, '.$_SESSION['username'];

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, post_user, post_title, post_description, post_info, post_date FROM posts");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   $post_id = $row['post_id'];
   $post_user = $row['post_user'];
   $post_title = $row['post_title'];
   $post_description = $row['post_description'];
   $post_info = $row['post_info'];
   $post_date = $row['post_date'];
   do { ?>

<article>
<h2>

<?php 
echo  $post_title; 
?>
</h2>
<?php
    echo $post_description;
    echo $post_info;
    echo 'Posted by '.$post_user.' on '.$post_date;

} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)); 
?>
</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better served to write your code like this (for example, from [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php))

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
}
```

Also please note that using mysql_* functions is not recommended, as these functions are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I worked out I had my do statement in the wrong place :)